# Delegate Method Missing Argument in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm pretty new to MonoTouch. I've got a question about a specific class that I'm trying to use, but I realize this may just be a limitation of my understanding of how the Objective-C world is translated into C#. Specifically, I'm trying to do a direct translation of Apple's *Touches* example into MonoTouch so I can make sure I understand how to do multitouch recognition correctly.

I'm trying to create a custom class derived from UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. This is the class which controls UIGestureRecogniser instances. I've managed to get most of it wired up correctly. However, one of the delegate methods seems to have a totally different signature in Objective-C than in MonoTouch, specifically:

**Objective-C:**

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

**MonoTouch:**

`public override bool ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously (UIGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer)`

As you can see, the Objective-C method takes two arguments of type UIGestureRecognizer, as it has to work with both of them; the MonoTouch one only seems to include the second of the two.

Again, I'm very happy to admit that I may have misunderstood something here - but I've looked through the documentation and forums as best I can (admittedly I don't really understand how all of this works just yet) and I couldn't see what to do here.

Any advice on how I can use this method would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, I've fixed it in the next version of monotouch (v4).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know when this might be released (either in beta or as a final version)?

Comment: Also, is there any way I could 'fix' or work around this myself for the time being, using a custom binding? (I did have a quick look at the documentation and it seems like I might be able to - but before I spend too much more time on this it would be good to know if this is possible.)

Comment: Just [Export] the selector yourself.